# Numpy : JSON encode images to file without closing the stream

Tags: python, json, numpy, serialization, raspberry-pi

I am creating training data where the idea is to capture images from a `PiCamera` and store them in a `JSON encoded` file that I can load later into my neural network for training.

Since I'm using a `Pi board`, memory is obviously a constraint.  Therefore I can't take a large amount of images and then serialize them at once.

I would like to serialize each image as I capture it, especially in case of failure, then I will not have lost all the data

```
def trainer(LEFT, RIGHT):
    # capture frames from the camera
    with open('robot-train.json', 'w') as train_file:
       writer =  csv.writer(open('robot-train.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
       for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
            data = {}
            # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp

            data['image'] = frame.array
            data['time'] = time.time()
            data['left'] = LEFT
            data['right'] = RIGHT

            # human readable version
            writer.writerow([data['time'], data['left'], data['right']])
            train_file.write(json.dumps(data, cls=NumpyEncoder))
            # prepare for next image
            rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

However I'm getting the error

```
  File "/home/pi/pololu-rpi-slave-arduino-library/pi/xiaonet.py", line 30, in default
    return json.JSONEncoder(self, obj)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: recursion of what function?

Comment: edited .. error above